# ReactJS - How to mock fetch of XML file in test?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

I try to fetch data from an local XML file witch is not working in the testcase but the app work correctly in the browser.
Im using Mock service worker to mock an api call in my testcase but not sure if this is possible to do directly with a local XML file instead of acctually passing a rest-ful url instead.

Here is my code:

Component:

```
function MunicipalityInfo() {
  const [municipalityData, setMunicipalityData] = useState({})

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try{
      const result = await fetch(XMLFile)
      const data = await result.text();
      const xml = new XMLParser().parseFromString(data);
      const res = XMLMapper(xml) <---- creates an object of the XML data
      setMunicipalityData(res)
    }catch(e){
      console.log(e)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
    setInterval(fetchData, 600000);
  }, []); 

  return(
    <>
      { municipalityData.units &&
        municipalityData.units.map((city, index) => {
          return (
            <Div key={index} data-testid="municipalityInfo-component" className="mt-5 p-3">
              <MapLink href={"#"} data-testid="map-link"><i data-testid="map-icon" className="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>Show on map</MapLink>
              <LinkList data-testid="link-list">
                <LinkListItem data-testid="list-item-first">
                  <Link href={city.BookingURL} data-testid="link-book-vaccination">Booking link</Link>
                </LinkListItem>
              </LinkList>
            </Div>
          )
        })
      }
    </>
  )
}
```

Test file:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import MunicipalityInfo from './MunicipalityInfo';
import {setupServer} from 'msw/node';
import {rest} from 'msw';

const data = {
    units: [
          {
            BookingURL: "https://someurl1.com"
        },
        {
            BookingURL: "https://someurl2.com"
        }
    ]
  }

  // Mocking service provider says the following:
  // Warning: captured a request without a matching request handler:
  
    // • GET http://localhost/data.xml

   When i go to this url i get a blank page...i dont acctually se the XML file with its data.


  const server = setupServer(
    rest.get("http://localhost/data.xml", (req, res, ctx) => {
      return res(ctx.json(data.units));
    })
  )

  beforeAll(() => server.listen())
  afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers())
  afterAll(() => server.close())


  describe("<MunicipalityInfo />", () => {
    it("renders without crashing", async () => {
        render(<MunicipalityInfo />);
    })

    it("render with the correct elements and values", async() => {
        render(<MunicipalityInfo />);
        const mapLink = await screen.findAllByTestId("map-link");
        const bookingLink = await screen.findAllByTestId("link-book-vaccination");

        expect(mapLink.length).toBe(2);
        expect(bookingLink.length).toBe(2);
    })
  })
```

Test error message:

```
  ● <MunicipalityInfo /> › render with the correct elements and values

    Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="map-link"]

    <body>
      <div />
    </body>

      33 |     it("render with the correct elements and values", async() => {
      34 |         render(<MunicipalityInfo />);
    > 35 |         const mapLink = await screen.findAllByTestId("map-link");
         |                                      ^
      36 |         const bookingLink = await screen.findAllByTestId("link-book-vaccination");
      37 |
      38 |         expect(mapLink.length).toBe(2);

      at waitForWrapper (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/wait-for.js:173:27)
      at findAllByTestId (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:101:33)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/Components/MunicipalityInfo/MunicipalityInfo.test.js:35:38)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 5 passed, 6 total
Tests:       1 failed, 10 passed, 11 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.403 s
```

As you can se the message in the error shows the html and that its not populated with data.

Im a missing something or is it not possible to make a fetch to my XML file this way?
The application i working fine in the browser but the test fails with the error i postded above.

Comment: If you have imported the file, you can just use it. There's no need to fetch it first. fetch is for loading resources from the server. Try `console.log(XMLFile)` to see how webpack has processed it. You can also use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-loader) and you should be able to access the data directly.

Comment: Actually i will need to fetch the xml from a url later but i have tested that and i get the same problem and i dont know why

Comment: Is it a public URL with CORS enabled? What is the exact error?

Comment: Its a local url on the server where the react app is going to be hosted

Comment: Please show your actual code. [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68297862/edit) and put it inside.

Comment: I now updated the code :)

Comment: So to be the clear, the error/issue is now completely different from what the question title says?

Comment: You need to mock the `XMLFile` endpoint—the one you `fetch` with MSW. The warning message you see means that the handler you've created doesn't match the actual request that's being made in your test. Inspect closely and see what's the difference between the two. I recommend not including any `localhost` in your handlers. If it's a relative URL, just provide it as-is: `rest.get('/data.xml', resolver)`.